# Prompt, Alerts, and IF statements

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, alert, prompt

I am working on my very first JS project. We must use prompts that ask the user for information, and return an alert based on their answer. When I run the first IF statement, the prompt box appears, and I can enter an answer to get the alert. When I add my 2 remaining IF statements, no prompt box appears at all. I've just begun learning this material. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var age = prompt('what is your age?');

if (age < 18) {
  alert("Wow! You are still young.");
} else if (age >= 19 && = < 23) {
  alert("Hmm, you are getting your years in.");
} else(age > 24) {
  alert("Wow, you are really old!");
}
```

Comment: `( age >= 19 && =< 23) ` should be `( age >= 19 && age <= 23)`, else does not need `( )` part

Comment: Each clause of a boolean statement is evaluated separately. You can't do things like `value >= x && <= y` because the second part (`<= y`) is entirely separate from the first part. It would be `value >= x && value <= y`. And not only does `else` *not need* a condition, it doesn't take one in the first place.

Comment: Also just to be clear, the less than or equal operator is `<=` not `= <`. And just for the record, if your final else statement was an else if, your condition (`age > 24`) would make your block not execute anything if age were to be exactly 24.

Comment: thank you everyone! This is solved with your help! Many thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

You should write `(age >= 19 && age <= 23)` instead of `(age >= 19 && = < 23)` and `else(age > 24)` will only `else`.

```
var age = prompt('what is your age?');

if (age < 18) {
    alert("Wow! You are still young.");
} else if (age >= 19 && age <= 23) {
    alert("Hmm, you are getting your years in.");
} else {
    alert("Wow, you are really old!");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

else only can't has any expression

```
if (age < 18) {
  alert("Wow! You are still young.");
} else if (age >= 19 && age <= 23) {
  alert("Hmm, you are getting your years in.");
} else {
  alert("Wow, you are really old!");
}
```

Comment: You only hit on half of the problem, and added nothing more than the comments above.

Comment: Sorry i copied the code without see that second expression was wrong